# Substitute password in helm values file prometheus blackbox exporter http target

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets, prometheus-blackbox-exporter, helm-tls

I'm trying to do an aliveness-check to rabbitmq management console via http api. I have the target in the helm values file under endpoints; I'm using http probe.

```
endpoints:
    - module: rabbit_alive_check
      port: http
      scheme: http
      url: "http://username:password@nodeip:15672/api/aliveness-test/%2F"
```

The output comes as expected. But I'm looking to substitute the password which I've already encrypted in helm secrets and not have it hardcoded in the url. I adopted prometheus-blackbox exporter from https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-blackbox-exporter.

How to call the password from helm secrets.yaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot inject secret value into `values.yaml`, since `values.yaml` is actually the input for your Helm Chart and it does not use any substitution.

I'm not sure where the code excerpt comes from, but a possible workaround for health checks could be having a custom script.

Comment: Is there a way I can add it to templates so it can pick?

Comment: As always with secrets you can either inject it as env variable or mount as a volume. Also, obviously, you can use Kubernetes API to fetch it. Saying that, there is nothing like automatic resolution to the template files.